# Secure delete files

Tags: windows, security, cleaner

I have a folder which I need to secure delete. I tried [File Shredder](http://www.fileshredder.org/) and [BleachBit](https://www.bleachbit.org/) but I got error because the files were in use or priviledge problems. Is there a program to delete files and restart computer if needed? I prefer free or open source also trials would be fine. My OS is Windows 10 x64.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [Eraser](https://eraser.heidi.ie):

- You can create a [task](https://eraser.heidi.ie/creating-tasks/) to run on reboot.
- It overwrites data several times using chosen patterns/algorithms.
- Supports Windows 10 and even Windows XP etc.
- It is free.

I have used it for years.

Comment: Hi, I noticed that it doesn't restart pc if needed, it gives me error.

Comment: Hi. I believe when I used in past, it did. Maybe anti-virus stopping it?

Comment: Thanks for helping, it happens on clean files either. Actually I couldn't execute task "run on reboot". When I restart pc the directory is still there.

Comment: Most of time I used it, I did not require reboot. Best to search their forum https://eraser.heidi.ie/forum/ or post a question there.